# accessing id property via javascript

Tags: javascript, dom

Is there a way to access the ID of a DOM element?

I don't mean using the getElementById method to get an array of objects.

Basically I already know the DOM element and that object reference is at hand.

All I need is to access the ID property.

I know something like

```
if(element.id==value)
```

won't work.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It should work, your problem lies somewhere else. Please provide a bit more context and a self-containing code example.

Comment: does it even have an id?

Comment: Ah, you're using jQuery. You should have explicitly mentioned and tagged that. jQuery != JavaScript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code should work if the `element` variable holds the dom element reference and it has an id defined..

Keep in mind that `getElementById` will not return an array of object but a single object. You might be confusing it with `getElementsByTagName`.

Comment: ty,
sorry I forgot to mention,
I am incorporating Jquery syntax into the equation.

$(this).id

Is there an jquery syntax for that

Comment: See Pointy's answer above. $(this).attr('id')

Comment: @webzide, as @kerry mentioned, have a look at Pointy's answer for the jquery syntax..  ( *and also accept it as this is how thing are done around here ;)* )

Answer (score 3):

In jQuery it's

```
 $(this).attr('id')
```

or

```
 $(this)[0].id
```

Answer (score 1):

It's works.

```
element.getAttribute('id');
```

Answer (score 1):

I've verified that both `element.id` and `element.getAttribute('id')` work in Chrome/Safari/FF latest and IE 6-8.